# Magento Debugging Environment

Tags: php, debugging, magento

I looked for ideas on setting up a Magento development environment when we first started using it for our site last year.  I didn't find anything that work really well, so I stayed with var_dump'ing using the log files.

Now that Magento has another year under its belt and several hundred more developers I was wondering if anyone has found a better solution for debugging Magento.

We use Eclipse as our development environment.  We tried a pre-2.0 release of PDT with the Zend Debugger and didn't have much luck.

Comment: Has anyone used Zend Server CE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using FirePHP?

http://ajzele.net/utilize-firebug-and-firephp-to-speed-up-magento-development

It made my life a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: I'm giving this the "Answer Flag" because of the effort/reward of getting Firephp up and running.  I am going to deep dive the xDebug environment a try when I get some time.

Comment: Hi, I tried it today and the link is broken, any alternatives?

Comment: Some Comments: Fire php should be enabled (of course) and the site you want to debug from Firephp (blue bug) -> Allowed sites menu. Also after copying the function some apostrophe (`) characters should become double quotes("). Thanx!

Answer (score 4):

I use a combination of `var_dump` with [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/) **and** Magento's [Mage::Log](http://alanstorm.com/magento_log_and_developer_mode) method.  Mage::Log is particularly nice, as it'll do some auto-expanding and pretty printing of objects if you pass them in (I'm not sure if that's the logger, or just Magento's __toString implementation).

If I'm on my local development box I use Console.app to keep an eye on the log file, otherwise it's a simple

```
tail -f /path/to/log/file
```

That combined with some custom modules I've built for debugging the config and layout keep me happy. (although I prefer a light weight text editor toolchain vs. the One True IDE tool chain, so your results may vary)

Comment: Do you MAMP or other "all-in-one" AMP stack?  I use MAMP, but will switch if it's easier to setup xDebug.

Comment: The Zend Framework is just a PHP Library, xDebug plays fine with it (you might be thinking of the Zend Platform)

Answer (score 3):

logging $object->getData() rather than the $object itself is normally more useful, and everything built into Magento has it as a method (everything extends Varien_Object)

Answer (score 1):

$object->debug() is often quite helpful too, although it doesn't exist on all objects.
Here are my most commonly logged statements:

```
Mage::log( $object->debug() )
Mage::log( $object->getData() )
Mage::log( get_class($object) )           # name of class
Mage::log( get_class_methods($object) )   # methods of class
```

Comment: I used your tip to plug krumo() in, and found that I got the items I need off the object by using get_object_vars().

Answer (score 0):

I also use FirePHP but find [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/2999) easier.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try to Magneto-Debug: https://github.com/madalinoprea/magneto-debug (only for dev environments).

Video doesn't contain features added in the latest version: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqvgrmebcu4
  - display layout updates from DB
  - display blocks' rendering time

Answer (score 0):

NuSphere is also good debugger for magento here is link
[NuSphere](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped_new_features.htm)